# Performe OpenCL zero-copy

Tags: opencl

I am starting with OpenCL, I work with OpenCL 1.2 Full Profile device. I would like to perform zero-copy.

Now I do

```
// creation of an input vector
int *A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*LIST_SIZE);

//OpenCL buffer to create
cl_mem a_obj = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,sizeof(int),A,&ret);
//Enabling the "pinned memory"
void* p_map_input = clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue,a_obj,CL_TRUE,CL_MAP_READ,0,sizeof(int),0,NULL,NULL,&ret);
...
...
...
// Setting the arguments of the kernel
ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),(void *)&a_obj);
//Execute the OpenCL kernel 
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue,kernel,1,NULL,&g_item_size, &l_item_size,0,NULL,&ev);
```

I would like to understand more on what and how to use pointer  *p_map_input* of *clEnqueueMapBuffer* and properly map to *A* input vector ?

How do I find out the zero-copy is applied and function? For now I measure overall execution time of an application with/without zero-copy and expecting improvement.

Thank you for advice.

Comment: Which device are you using? Zero copy is not possible on all devices.

Comment: I have GPU: Intel Gen9 HD Graphics NEO.

Comment: [The Intel guide should have all the answers you need](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-the-most-from-opencl-12-how-to-increase-performance-by-minimizing-buffer-copies-on-intel-processor-graphics)

Comment: is there *Linux* version of OpenCL Zero Copy code sample?

Comment: If I recall correctly all samples [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl-support/code-samples) use zero copy in both Linux and Windows

Comment: I downloaded the zero copy sample from page you provided first and other has zero copy sample as well?

Comment: Not zero copy specifically but all of the samples should use zero copy by themselves

Comment: I fixed OpenCL Zero Copy code sample for linux to compile, it's ending with Sucess!... but should I see performance improvement and measure app time execution?

Comment: That depends entirely how large portion of the programs run time is spent on the data transfers. You can use the OpenCL events to find out how long each data transfer takes.

Comment: funny thing is I use either clock() or gettimeofday() I see quite discrepancy. still investigate ...